# Why iphone freezes receiving rainbow flag?

Tags: ios, iphone, message, freeze

recently I come along this bug, where incoming message to iphone, with 3 consecutive emoticons: white_flag, zero, rainbow... completely freeze the whole iphone.

I'm curious about explanation of, what could cause this crash?
What is happening behind the scenes?

I just can't imagine, how translating some 3 icons from incoming message into some other icon, could basically lock all resources of phone to itself.

Can somebody, who have some background in objective C and creating applications for IOS, give me some better explanation, than "Yeah man, it freezes." ?

Comment: http://preston159.com/bug-technical.html

Comment: Obviously, it's homophobic.

Answer (score 0):

Because, iPhone is trying to make a rainbow flag, but it isn’t in its database, causing it to crash.

Comment: But that was a long time ago, now there is a rainbow flag, but ️0 was never linked to ️‍, causing some phones to crash.